# jquery radio value always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of the radio button selected

HTML

```
<form id='formTeacherOptions' method='post' target='_self' action='static.php'>       
    <div id='subjectoptions'>
        <input name='radioGrpSbjOption' type='radio' value='0' /> View Subject <br />
        <input name='radioGrpSbjOption' type='radio' value='1' /> Update Subject <br />            
     </div>
     <div id='testoption'>
        <input name='radioGrpSbjOption' type='radio' value='2' /> Create Test 
        <div id='testoptionsubjects'> </div>
        <div id='testoptiontopic'> </div>

        <br />
        <input name='radioGrpSbjOption' type='radio' value='3' /> View/Update Test <br />
        <input name='radioGrpSbjOption' type='radio' value='4' /> Activated Test <br />
     </div>
     <div id='reportoptions'>
        <input name='radioGrpSbjOption' type='radio' value='5' /> Quiz Report <br />
        <input name='radioGrpSbjOption' type='radio' value='6' /> Exam Report <br />
     </div>
     <button id='' type='button'> Submit </button>
  </form>
```

JS

```
$('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]').bind('change', function (){
   alert ($('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]').val());
})
```

The value returned is always 0. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use `:checked` selector

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the selector thing before.

Comment: You code `$('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]')` find all radios and returns first one value that is `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:checked` selector

```
   alert ($('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]:checked').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]').bind('change', function (){
   alert ($(this).val());
})
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17sounwe/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your code `$('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]')` find all radios and returns first one value that is `0`. so change you code to this:

```
$('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]').bind('change', function (){
    alert ($('input[name="radioGrpSbjOption"]:checked').val());
});
```

it uses [:checked](http://jqapi.com/#p=checked-selector) selector to find the selected inputs with `name="radioGrpSbjOption"`

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aeumbqyt/)